# How to Convert Model Object to JSON

Tags: ios, json

How can i convert model Object to JSON Format Without Using any frameworks ?

```html
@interface modelData : NSObject

// store name
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;

// store release date
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *releaseDate;

//store image
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *image;

// init with local json
-(instancetype)initWithName :(NSString*)name withReleaseDate:(NSString*)releaseDate withImage:(NSString*)imageName;

@end
```

Comment: Using `NSJSONSerialization`. But it clearly depends on how the JSON should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this without other frameworks you can create some method like :

```
- (NSDictionary *)toJSON {
    return @{
        @"image" : self.image,
        @"releaseDate" : self.releaseDate,
        @"name" : self.name
    };
}
```

So if object looks like this `modelData("imageName","01.05.2016","name")` the `toJSON` method gives you :

`{
    "image" : "imageName",
    "releaseDate" : "01.05.2016",
    "name" : "name"
 }`

So the

`NSDictionary *dict = [modelObjectInstance toJSON]`

gives you `NSDictionary` with you object.

Then you can get JSON string by :

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];
if (! data) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

**Important**

Please remember that it will work when your objects are simple, like in your example (it have only `NSString` properties). If you have a more complex object with a  some custom classes properties. You have to provide more logic to create that json in that way.

Comment: NSDictionary -description doesn't really give you a valid JSON string, you need to use NSJSONSerialization for that.

Comment: @FilipRadelic you right. I made some changes regarding to your comment.